# Applying css in functions.php

Tags: php, css

does anyone know how i can style the content i echo out in functions.php with the style.css, just how i would if it was html instead of php? Or whichever other way i can style it, as long as it works. For simplicities shake, lets take this hook:
function the_function(){
echo '

Hello world

';
}
add_action( 'get_sidebar', 'the_function' );
How do i add background colors, move it around the space, and all that, as if its html code? Btw, i m using a child theme if it matters, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is HTML code. If you look at the front end of the website and inspect the HTML using the browser's developer tools you'll see that it just outputs HTML that you can style like any other HTML.

Comment: Thank you, i made 2 other comments asking for further questions but i seem to have solved them after all.